# use of だって after 私

Tags: usage, word-usage

[image]

I was making some sentence cards and was wondering what だって in this case meant.

I got sth like "**Even I** am of use as splendid maid for Kobayashi."

for context: Lucoa was summoned by Shota but doesn't want to leave. Tohru tells her, she can't just stay for free.

Comment: Do you mean「だって」after「私」？

Comment: yeah exaxtly. I edited it hanks ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that’s right. In particular, it gives the flavor of making a counterargument to something that was already stated. So one could imagine that the context is about Lucoa not being useful, and she is trying argue against that.